# Has Node.js Currency symbol for Australian dollar, AUD, been changed after v12?

Tags: node.js, locale, currency-formatting

```js
(100.2).toLocaleString('en-AU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'AUD' })
```

From my nvm, above code in nodejs v12 gives `'A$100.20'`
but in nodejs v14 and v16, it gives `'$100.20'`

Did I miss something?
Not sure why this result differs and what is correct. Could someone refer to the documentation?

BTW, Old Chromium version gives also `A$` (`Version 44.0.2403.0`)
But latest gives just `$`

---

Tried some docker images to get node and v8 versions

```
➜ docker run -it whitech/dind:14.21 ash -c "node -v && node -p process.versions.v8 && node -e \"console.log('icu_small:', process.config.variables.icu_small) || console.log((100.2).toLocaleString('en-AU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'AUD' }))\""
v14.21.3
8.4.371.23-node.88
icu_small: true
A$100.20
➜ docker run -it whitech/dind:14.20 ash -c "node -v && node -p process.versions.v8 && node -e \"console.log('icu_small:',process.config.variables.icu_small) || console.log((100.2).toLocaleString('en-AU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'AUD' }))\""
v14.20.1
8.4.371.23-node.87
icu_small: true
A$100.20
➜ docker run -it node:14.19.3-alpine3.14 ash -c "node -v && node -p process.versions.v8 && node -e \"console.log('icu_small:',process.config.variables.icu_small) || console.log((100.2).toLocaleString('en-AU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'AUD' }))\""
v14.19.3
8.4.371.23-node.87
icu_small: false
$100.20
```

and my local

```
➜  nvm use 14
Now using node v14.21.3 (npm v6.14.18)
➜  node -v && node -p process.versions.v8 && node -e "console.log('icu_small:',process.config.variables.icu_small) || console.log((100.2).toLocaleString('en-AU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'AUD' }))"
v14.21.3
8.4.371.23-node.88
icu_small: false
$100.20
➜  nvm use 14.19.3
Now using node v14.19.3 (npm v6.14.17)
➜  node -v && node -p process.versions.v8 && node -e "console.log('icu_small:',process.config.variables.icu_small) || console.log((100.2).toLocaleString('en-AU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'AUD' }))"
v14.19.3
8.4.371.23-node.87
icu_small: false
$100.20
➜  nvm use 12
Now using node v12.22.12 (npm v6.14.16)
➜  node -v && node -p process.versions.v8 && node -e "console.log('icu_small:',process.config.variables.icu_small) || console.log((100.2).toLocaleString('en-AU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'AUD' }))"
v12.22.12
7.8.279.23-node.57
icu_small: true
A$100.20
```

BTW, [whitech/dind:14.21](https://hub.docker.com/layers/whitech/dind/14/images/sha256-ebfb3f1055c14a7dd07721f61ba03f16a62edc9cd0acfb9e22ea444faa4361b6?context=explore) was probably built based on `docker:24.0.3-dind`
and installed nodejs by

```
apk --no-cache add --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main "nodejs<14.99"
```

** If I used node v12 and install full-icu(1.5.0), and specified it with `NODE_ICU_DATA`, it gave `$100.20` again. Interesting.

```
NODE_ICU_DATA=./node_modules/full-icu node -e "console.log((100.2).toLocaleString('en-AU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'AUD' }))"
$100.20
```

Comment: Small note: the current oldest LTS version of Node is 16, with the "normal" current LTS being 18. If you're asking about 14, you're asking about a version that reached EOL several months ago... That said, Node uses the V8 JS engine used in Chrome, so if Chrome changes things, Node ends up "inheriting" those changes.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back but I wanted to from which LTS version that behaviour has changed. I'd like to remove v14 from the title. Yeah now I wonder why V8 has changed the behaviour.

Comment: Because, if you're in Australia, you write the amount as `$100.20`.  You do not write `A$100.20`.  Just like we in America don't write `US$100.10` unless it's in a specific context where there might be confusion.

Comment: I think it's probably related to this https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19214 I think `toLocaleString` should be affected by ICU data and it would depend which ICU data has been used by default. (in node.js build time) `$100.20` is what `full-icu` consistently is saying